# How to keep header the same size as the window

Tags: html, css

I am a total beginner and i have a problem with a header width (i am also not so great English speaker so i hope that i will manage to explain this good as i need to).
Header is marked in css as 100% but when i change size of the firefox or chrome window it stays with width of the monitor and i get that drag line down on the browser window. 
Everything else on site follows the size of the window, only that stays big.
Also they all have position:relative.
This is the html code:

```
<header>
        <div id="adresa">
            <ul>
              <li><img name="telefon" src="Prvisajt/Rounded-16-128.png" width="20"; height="18"; align="bottom";> 011/2762-124 </li>
              <li>&emsp; <img name="adresa" src="Prvisajt/location-square-social-media-128.png" width="20"; height="18"; align="bottom";> Ruzveltova 45, 11000 Beograd, Frizerski salon Marko</li>
              <li id="mail"><a href="mailto:kontakt@frizerskisalonmarko.com"> <img src="Prvisajt/mail-square-social-media-128.png" width="20"; height="18"; align="bottom"> </a></li> 
              <li id="face"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/FSM.Beograd/"> <img src="Prvisajt/Facebook_social_media_logo-128.png" width="20"; height="18"; align="bottom"> </a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>

       <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><img id="logo" src="Prvisajt/logo-alternate.png" alt="Logo"></li>
            <li><a href="galerija.html">GALERIJA</a></li>
            <li><a href="cenovnik.html">CENOVNIK</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>  





and this is css:



body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar {
    width:100%;
    height:92px;
    float: right;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;

}

#navbar ul li {
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    left: 970px;
}

#navbar li a {
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -16px;
    right: 620px;
}

#adresa {
    float: left;
    display:inline;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}

#adresa ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: 350px;
}


#mail img {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    right: -600px;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#face img {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    right: -610px;
    border-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: You have given `#navbar ul li` `left: 970px` and `#logo` `right: 620px`. Same in other css. That is causing the problem. You have to give them percentage value too, or some reasonable fixed pixels.

Comment: One more thing is, don't use `left` and `right` with `position: relative` elements. Use `margin` or `padding` instead.

Comment: I can say that the first answer here, adding tag in head section didn't help... Header still stays larger then window. Also when i put width and height to 100% it is not ok. Because they are pictures they became too large and it is all out of order.

Comment: In that case you can set `max-height` and `max-width`.

Comment: That helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is responsiveness if I'm not wrong, so what you need to do is
add a meta tag to you head section like this:

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

And instead go for a responsive CSS framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: why should he go for a responsive framework if he just needs some percentage values???
so comparing a bit of css may 5Kb vs Bootstrap 121kb -> and im just talking about the bootstrap.min.css

Comment: upvoted for the meta tag suggestion - agree with @MarcelD that Bootstrap is bloated!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the width and height of the images to 100%

```
#adresa ul li img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

This should fix it.

Comment: I can say that the first answer here, adding tag in head section didn't help... Header still stays larger then window. Also when i put width and height to 100% it is not ok. Because they are pictures they became too large and it is all out of order.

Answer (score 0):

remove left property and add `float: right;`
then add this
`#adresa ul li img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
}`